# Array Looping Structure

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I have been trying to loop a series of answers that match in two arrays. The code runs through the loop each time and outputs the first 20 questions, but won't go on to the next set to check those answers.

answeredCorrectly is a counter
studentAnswers is an array of 100 questions being matched to the array correctAnswers sized at 20.
QUESTIONS is the constant int valued at 20 and paired with correctAnswers.

I tried forgoing the for loop structure and just use while loops that checked the position in studentAnswers, but that resulted in a crash.

Any ideas to continue the counter for each of the other students instead of sticking with the first 20 answers?

Here is the section of code that I am dealing with.

*EDIT* 
Added the function createReport2()

*EDIT 2*
Added updated code

```
string createReport2 (int questNum, char stuResponse, char correctResponse)
{
stringstream ss;  // the string stream object that will be used for the conversions

// Add the various elements to the stringstream object.
ss << questNum << "(" << stuResponse << "/" << correctResponse << ")";

// Return the final result as a C++ string class.
return ss.str();
} // end function string createReport (int questNum, char stuResponse, char correctResponse)

int main()
{
    const int QUESTIONS = 20; 
    const int STUDENT_QUESTIONS = 100;
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("CorrectAnswers.txt");
    char correctAnswers[QUESTIONS];
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        inputFile >> correctAnswers[i]; 
    }

    ifstream inputFile2;
    inputFile2.open("StudentAnswers.txt");
    char studentAnswers[STUDENT_QUESTIONS];
    for (int t=0; t<STUDENT_QUESTIONS; t++)
    {
        inputFile2 >> studentAnswers[t];
    }

int answeredCorrectly = 0;
string name;

for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    {
    string arr[100];
    for (int x=0; x < QUESTIONS; x++)
        {      
            if (studentAnswers[(5*c)+x] == correctAnswers[x])
                answeredCorrectly++;
            else
                arr[c*5+x] = createReport2(x,studentAnswers[c*5+x],correctAnswers[x]);
        }

                cout << "Report for Student " << c+1 << ":" << endl;
                cout << "---------------------" << endl;
                cout << "Missed " << 20 - answeredCorrectly << " out of 20 questions for " << (answeredCorrectly / 20.0) * 100 << "% correct." << endl;
                cout << "Answered Correctly:  " << answeredCorrectly << endl;
                cout << "Questions missed:";
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    cout << arr[c*5+i];
                }
                cout << endl << endl;

                answeredCorrectly = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `...[x]` `->` `studentAnswers[QUESTIONS*c+x]` + refactoring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a quick fix would be to put `studentAnswers[(20*c)+x]` whereever you have `studentAnswers[x]`.

You should actually have student answers in a 2 dimensional array (`studentAnswers[STUDENTS][QUESTIONS]`, where STUDENTS would be 5) though.

There's a possible of-by-1 in `createReport2()`, where questNum could possibly be changed to `questNum+1`.

Also, declare `string arr[20]` *inside* the main for loop. OR Change `arr[x]` to `arr[c*20+x]`, and `arr[i]` to `arr[c*20+i]`.

Edit: So to summarize

```
for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
{
    for (int x=0; x < QUESTIONS; x++)
    {      
        if (studentAnswers[c*20+x] == correctAnswers[x])
            answeredCorrectly++;
        else
            arr[c*20+x] = createReport2(x,studentAnswers[c*20+x],correctAnswers[x]);
    }

    cout << "Report for Student " << c+1 << ":" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Missed " << 20 - answeredCorrectly 
         << " out of 20 questions for " << (answeredCorrectly / 20.0) * 100 
         << "% correct." << endl;
    cout << "Answered Correctly:  " << answeredCorrectly << endl;
    cout << "Questions missed:";
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[c*20+i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    answeredCorrectly = 0;
}
```

Comment: The parantheses arent neccessary as `*` binds stronger than `+` (even in mathematics o.O)

Comment: Yeah fair point, I was rushing. It's one of those uber uber basic things that I just get mixed up all of the time, so I go nuts with the brackets ;-)

Comment: It works successfully for the first run through the loop (referencing the quick fix), but completely breaks when moving on to the second loops. Probably because of createReport2()

Comment: You'll need to post createReport2(). My concern was what that function did!

Comment: Posted createReport2() in the main body

Comment: What do you mean with breaks? Crash or invalid output? Please be more concrete

Comment: The output on the first student is correct, then when it moves on to the second through fifth students, and it says 20 for 20 were incorrect (The second student is supposed to not miss any questions). Then when it goes to show the correct answers for the wrong ones, there are missing characters, numbers, etc.

Comment: @Simsyy Sorry, my error I think, it should be `studentAnswers[(5*c)+x]`, _not_ 20! That'll teach me for rushing!

Comment: Progress! It does build successfully and run with more accuracy but still things don't match up to the array 100%. It's getting really close though.

Comment: My mistake. Which bit isn't matching up now? Are the question numbers off by 1? If so, you need to be using questNum+1.

Comment: Student 1 is matching up correctly still. Student 2 should have a 100%. They didn't miss anything when manually looking at the input files. The output is saying that student 2 missed 7 questions and the report is creating  8 incorrect answers at a position that I cannot find manually in the input files. questnNum+1 did not solve anything

Comment: Have you tried hard-coding that data in to make sure it's the code that's the issue?

Comment: I think the issue is that we are moving the array of studentAnswers but not the one for correctAnswers

Comment: Edited my main answer - move `arr` inside the outer for-loop and you shouldn't get rubbish any more. I just checked it and it worked for me. Oops, I removed my last answer, but yes.

Comment: If you need to keep the incorrect answers in that 1-D array, you should insert and output the missed answers using `[c*5+i]` `[c*5+x]` instead of `[i]` and `[x]` respectively.

Comment: Is the wrongAnswers array still necessary? I got a little mixed up on building that. I'd prefer to keep it in the 1-D array since I have little/no experience with implementing 2D arrays.

Comment: Nah ignore that, I'm working off the top of my head. I'd give arr a better name, but using the indexing I gave you it should work correctly now. I've tested it with 3 students answering 4 questions and got the correct output.

Comment: Btw, you should accept/upvote the answers to other questions you've asked if they've helped.

Comment: I'm still confused as to what is indexing. Am I throwing the [c*5+i] in everywhere or in only specific places?

Comment: Where you have `arr[i]`, you now put `arr[c*5+i]`. Just there, i's not in scope anywhere else. You're using x in the first loop, hence arr[c*5+x] in that loop.

Comment: I did that previously thinking it was incorrect because it causes the program to output two of the students, the second one being incorrect, and then crashing.

Comment: Did you change `arr[x]` to `arr[c*5+x]`? This is working absolutely fine in my version now. What size have you made arr? It should be 100.

Comment: Yes, I have both of those changed. It still is causing the second-fifth students to have the wrong number of incorrect answers.

Comment: Then you must have forgotten `createReport2(x,studentAnswers[c*5+x],correctAnswers[x]);` if it's not crashing now. Are you just getting the same incorrect answers every time?

Comment: Literally everywhere in the function you've got `studentAnswers[x]`, you need `studentAnswers[c*5+x]`.

Comment: Ok, that solved the crashing problem, but for the students after the first one, the data isnt matching up. It still says the second student has 7 wrong answers when the txt files say he missed 0.

Comment: Bear in mind I've got no idea what your code looks like now, so I don't know what's been missed. Under the original code, post what you now have and I'll take a look.

Comment: `arr` shoudn't be inside the loop, move it outside and I think that'll do it.

Comment: `string arr[100]`? If so that did not change the output

Comment: Damn, I was actually right the first time when I said c*20 and not c*5. I just copied your code and had similar problems. Change `c*5` to `c*20` in the four places you see it and you'll get the right results. Sorry about that... I clearly did it right in my own code and put the wrong thing on here...

Comment: This time, I took a copy of your code (only replacing the file load with some in-code arrays) and got similar problems. Once I changed `c*5` to `c*20`, it started working. You also need to use `questNum+1` in createReport2() :-).

Comment: Its amazing how simple solutions can be sometimes. There is nothing to be sorry about. You stuck with this code and helped me out; I couldn't be more thankful. I'd buy you a beer if I could!

Comment: Lol, I'm slightly annoyed at leading myself astray when my first answer was almost right. I've got a beer now so it's all good!

Comment: That's coding in a nutshell! Same here, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a separate variable for incorrect answers something like answeredIncorrectly.

```
for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
    int answeredCorrectly = 0;
    int answeredIncorrectly = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < QUESTIONS; x++) {
        if (studentAnswers[x] == correctAnswers[x])
            answeredCorrectly++;
        else {
            arr[answeredIncorrectly] = createReport2(x, studentAnswers[x],
                    correctAnswers[x]);
            answeredIncorrectly++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Report for Student " << c + 1 << ":" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Missed " << 20 - answeredCorrectly
            << " out of 20 questions for "
            << (answeredCorrectly / 20.0) * 100 << "% correct." << endl;
    cout << "Answered Correctly:  " << answeredCorrectly << endl;
    cout << "Questions missed:";
    for (int i = 0; i < answeredIncorrectly; i++) {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    answeredCorrectly = 0;
}
```